# Is it normal to make a function which handles all errors?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, error-handling

I was adding error handling to my code, but I think it ruins the look of it completely. So I would like to make a function which does all the error handling, but I couldn't really find any examples online, so I tried to come up with something myself..

```
def checkerr(datatype,obj):    

    try:
        var=datatype(obj)
        return(var)
    except ValueError as error:
        print(error,'you did not type in an integer')        
    except IOError as error:
        print(error,'file could not be found')


no=input('type in an integer: ')
realno=checkerr(int,no)

file=input('type in a filenane: ')
realfile=checkerr(open,file)
```

How should it be done?

Comment: Consider: What would happen if someone entered invalid input? What would your program do? It would print a message, set the `no` or `file` variable to `None`, and continue to execute. Is that correct error handling?

Comment: Making a generic handler for error checking seems to be the wrong way to go since the possibilities could be endless depending on your use case.

Comment: The general rule of thumb is: if the local code knows how to handle an error it should handle it, if it doesn't know, then it should allow the error to "bubble up" to the next level. If that level knows how to handle the error, then it should do, otherwise it lets the error bubble up. Etc. If the topmost level doesn't know how to handle the error, the program should crash... and the programmer should fix the program. ;)

Comment: There _are_ sometimes cases where something like this is useful, generally when writing an adapter between two different APIs that have different notions of error-handling. But it's rare that you want such an adapter to swallow the errors—usually it's just a matter of raising a different (usually smaller, and more local) set of exception type, or returning a value, or something like that. (All of the examples I can think of are doing things like ctypes, or native-Java code in Jython, or wrapping up giant, clumsy, and ancient libraries, so I can't think of something worth linking to here…)

Answer (score 2):

You are on the good way. Defining this piece of code in a function allows you to [avoid repetitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).

But it would be probably better to re-ask the user until the input is valid, so that you can rely on the function returning always a good value.

Your function would return `None` after the first failed attempt. Then the code would get complicated again.

My suggestion:

```
def ask(prompt, datatype):
    while True:
        obj = input(prompt)
        try:
            var = datatype(obj)
            return(var)
        except (ValueError, IOError) as error:
            print(error)
```

Example:

```
>>> i = ask('type in an integer: ', int); print('you entered: %d' % i)
type in an integer: two
invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'two'
type in an integer: 2
you entered: 2
```

Comment: You probably want to change the error message "you did not type in an integer"—it doesn't do a very good job if, say, `datatype` is `float`. (In fact, I think just printing the `ValueError` alone is probably enough…)

Comment: yup, makes sense!